# how to use implicit intent in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, implicit

In my application, I created two activities. In activity1, I created a button, set event:
[image]

activity2, I created, and write in manifest:
[image]

when i click to the button in activity1, error was throw:
[image]

Why? Please explain to me. Thank you

I expect activity2 to run when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

I had find issue in your code.
Inside Click event of button change as per below.
use **startActivityForResult()**  instead of **startActivity()**.

It will works.

Comment: startActivityForResult() is deprecated, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ACTION_MAIN` instead of `ACTION_VIEW` as below inside your button click listener,

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALENDAR)
startActivity(intent)
```

You are getting this error because the `ACTION_VIEW` is related to the generic action like viewing various types of data like if you set the data for any website URL so the system will be capable to open the the browser as it is handling on this basis and in your case system is not able to find the particular intent as type of view for the calendar. While the calendar application is the for the type where we need to specify the entry point as in terms of opening the main screen of the application so that the system will understand to open the main part of the specific application. Whether both are the intent type but for the different category you must need to choose different one.